# Flatlib - bdist_wheel error

Tags: python, python-wheel

I am trying to install python flatlib, but i am getting an error:

Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyswisseph ... error.

Failed building wheel for pyswisseph

Collecting pyswissep
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyswissep (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyswissep

I have installed the latest Visual Studio C++ Build Tools.
I have run:

```
pip install -U setuptools
pip install - wheel
pip install update
easy_install -U pip
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I'm using Python 3.7 and Pip 18.0

The usual ideas i can find don't have any effect!

Can anyone help?

Cheers, Will

Comment: Can you do `pip install pyswissep` ?

Comment: Ah yes I have tried this and get the same error... I have also tried running the cmd prompt as administrator, but  neither work...

Comment: sorted this... after Python install run set CL=-DWIN32
py -m pip install flatlib